# Comparable<T> in a Boolean isBST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, comparable

So I understand what is going on inside of this method but am totally lost on how to write it. when i run this method i get with in my program i get. compareTo(T) in java.lang.Comparable cannot be applied to (java.lang.Comparable) on the **BOLDED** lines so hopefully you can point out what it is without me having to post all the different c;asses with it.

```html
public boolean isBST(BinaryTreeNode<T> tree){
    Comparable<T> temp1 = (Comparable<T>) tree.lLink.info;
    Comparable<T> temp2 = (Comparable<T>) tree.rLink.info;
    Comparable<T> temp3 = (Comparable<T>) tree.info;
    
    if (tree == null) 
      return true; 
    else if (tree.lLink != null) // && tree.lLink.info > tree.info) 
      return false ;
    **else if ( temp1.compareTo(temp3) > 0 )**
      return false;
    else if (tree.rLink != null) // && tree.rLink.info <= tree.info) 
      return false; 
    **else if ( temp2.compareTo(temp3) > 0 )**
      return false;
    else 
      return isBST(tree.lLink) && isBST(tree.rLink); 
  }//closes boolean isBST
```

Comment: Please provide the full definition of the `BinaryTreeNode<T>` class. It looks like you actually may not have properly defined `Comparable`s.